# I’m confused why this infinite geometric sum is true m

Tags: geometric-series

I’m really confused why this is true $$p \cdot \sum\limits_{i=m+1}^\infty (1-p)^{i-1} = (1-p)^m$$ 
I know the formula for the infinite geometric sum is $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty a r^i = \frac{a}{1-r}$$

Answer (score 2):

Read the formula for the sum of a geometric series as
$$\frac{\text{first term}}{\text{$1-$ common ratio}}.$$
Here the first term is obtained by plugging $i=m+1$:
$$p(1-p)^m$$
and the common ratio is:
$$1-p$$